# Office 365 Rest API - Access exchange custom fields/userproperties

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I am wondering if accessing exchange userpropeties from Office365 Rest APIs is possible ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog

I know this is possible with EWS (exchange web services) but couldn't find a way to do the same using REST APIs ?

If this is not yet available, Does anybody know when Microsoft will release this ?

Comment: Are there specific user properties you are looking for?

Comment: [exchange public strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.defaultextendedpropertyset(v=exchg.80).aspx) I know with EWS we can access any property using the property GUID as shown in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633654(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to store some application specific information inside the appointment, I think I should be looking at the **event object** specified in this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#EventoperationsCreateevents) but the hyperlink for the **event** is broken.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have this capability in REST API. If there are specific properties that you need for your scenario and can share, we can look at including those properties. If you are looking to store custom properties specific to your app, we have this on our roadmap. But I don't have a timeline to share with you.

Comment: Great ! Thanks for confirming.